# How to Access a cell in a dataframe, dataframe being contained in a list in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, indexing

I got a set of dataframes in r which I stored in a list.

`dfList = list(df1,df2)`

I can access df1 by typing
`dfList[[1]]`
in the terminal and I can access a cell by typing
`df1[x,y]`
but what would be the combination of those?

When I type
`dfList[[1]][x,y]`
I get the error that I picked too many dimensions.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  What are `x` and `y`?  Are those numeric index stored in a object

Comment: Using a reproducible example `dfList <- list(data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10), data.frame(A= letters[1:5], B = letters[6:10])); dfList[[1]][1, 2]#
[1] 6`

Comment: yes, ```x``` and ```y``` are the coordinates. Working on the example now

Comment: Sorry to bother you, i tried your example and it worked. My mistake was, that i had overwritten the list so it didnt contain dataframes anymore but rather a number, so I got an error "incorrect number of dimensions". When I googled that error, I didn't find the fix to my problem earlier.

Thanks for the reproducible example, it helped me figure it out :)